# cSplit library(splitstackshape) is always dropping the column

Tags: r, splitstackshape

I was searching for a way to split the column content by a separator and converting a table into a long format. I found `cSplit` from the `splitstackshape` package and it is almost doing what I was looking for.

Problem is now with the `drop` option. I expected my split column to be copied in a way, but this does not happen. Am I doing it wrong? Somebody experienced the problem?

I am not sure if I do something wrong, but the `drop = FALSE` option is not working in my case.

Here is an example:

```
library(splitstackshape)
jnk <- data.table(a = '1,2,3,4,5', b = 5)
jnk
#            a b
# 1: 1,2,3,4,5 5

cSplit(jnk, 'a', ',', 'long', drop = FALSE)
#    a b
# 1: 1 5
# 2: 2 5
# 3: 3 5
# 4: 4 5
# 5: 5 5
```

What I expected was something like this:

```
cSplit(jnk, 'a', ',', 'long', drop = FALSE)
#    a b    a.orig
# 1: 1 5 1,2,3,4,5
# 2: 2 5 1,2,3,4,5
# 3: 3 5 1,2,3,4,5
# 4: 4 5 1,2,3,4,5
# 5: 5 5 1,2,3,4,5
```

I am using version 1.4.2

Comment: This does for sure not work if there are more lines in the df, since the `jnk[['a']]` needs to have the same length or it gets appended each time... So it is not working with `jnk <- data.table(a=c('1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3','2,3'),b=c(5,4,3))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "long" format modifies the column in place using `list(unlist(...))` within "data.table", assigned with `:=`. Hence, if `drop` were used, you would be splitting the column and then removing it!

I'll try to make it explicit in the documentation that `drop` is only for the `wide` format, or add a `message` if a user attempts to use `drop` in the long format. Feel free to [file a FR or submit a PR](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/issues).

The workaround would be to assign another column (say, "a_orig") and then do the splitting:

```
jnk <- data.table(a=c('1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3','2,3'),b=c(5,4,3))
cSplit(jnk[, a_orig := a], "a", ",", "long")
#     a b    a_orig
#  1: 1 5 1,2,3,4,5
#  2: 2 5 1,2,3,4,5
#  3: 3 5 1,2,3,4,5
#  4: 4 5 1,2,3,4,5
#  5: 5 5 1,2,3,4,5
#  6: 1 4     1,2,3
#  7: 2 4     1,2,3
#  8: 3 4     1,2,3
#  9: 2 3       2,3
# 10: 3 3       2,3
```

---

I haven't tested extensively, but a possible fix could be:

```
cSplit2 <- function(indt, splitCols, sep = ",", direction = "wide", 
                    fixed = TRUE, drop = TRUE, stripWhite = TRUE, 
                    makeEqual = NULL, type.convert = TRUE) {
  if (direction == "long" & !drop) {
    indt <- as.data.table(indt)
    indt[, `:=`(eval(paste(splitCols, "orig", sep = "_")),
                lapply(splitCols, function(x) indt[[x]]))]
  }
  cSplit(indt, splitCols, sep, direction, fixed, drop, stripWhite, 
         makeEqual, type.convert)
}
```

The basic idea is to only change the input dataset if `direction == "wide"` and `drop = FALSE`. This is similar to the idea that you had, but can *possibly* be the solution integrated into the actual package, somewhere around [line 94](https://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape/blob/master/R/cSplit.R#L94). In this case, only the `` indt[, `:=`(eval(paste(splitCols, "orig", sep = "_")), lapply(splitCols, function(x) indt[[x]]))] `` part should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback, I wrote a little function as a workaround.
I had to change the `data.table` into `data.frame` to get it to work properly. In case of the `data.table` I need to set an additional parameter but it crashes with `data.frame`. In my case I need most of the time `data.frame` so I optimised it for it.

```
library(splitstackshape)
jnk <- data.frame(a = c('1,2,3,4,5','1,2,3','2,3'),
                  b = c('a,b,c,d,e','a,b,c','a,b'),
                  c = c(5,4,3))
jnk

myCSplit <- function(data_set, splitCols, sep = ',', direction = 'long', drop = TRUE, ...) {
  if(direction == 'long' & !drop) {
    orig_names <- sub('$', '_orig', splitCols)
    df <- as.data.frame(data_set[,splitCols])
    names(df) <- orig_names
    df2 <- cbind(data_set, df)
    return(cSplit(df2, splitCols, sep, 'long'))
  } else {
    return(cSplit(data_set, splitCols, sep, direction, drop = drop,...))
  }
}
myCSplit(jnk, 'a', ',')
myCSplit(jnk, 'a', ',', drop = FALSE)
myCSplit(jnk, 'a', ',', 'wide')
myCSplit(jnk, 'a', ',', 'wide', drop = FALSE)
myCSplit(jnk, c('a','b'), ',', 'long', drop = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hey @AnandaMahto maybe you could add this feature to the next release... In my case it would be very useful.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it *should* be possible for me to make the fix with just one line. I'll have to do some tests to see though.